# Summation Error (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

From the image above, I want to sum the Time Spent column in my SSRS report. The issue is that this is not an int column but a varchar (after finding the difference between two datetime columns). I want my result set to be in the format - 00:00:00 (form of hh:mm:ss).
The sql query looks like:
CONVERT(Varchar(10), Dateadd(Second, DATEDIFF(Second,StartDate,FinishedDate),0), 108)  AS SpentTime
What do I have to do to get the right values back?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using VARCHAR formatting in the SQL procedure, you can send the TimeSpent as a time data type and then you can use the  expression below.  You can then format the time within the report itself instead using text box properties.

`=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TimeSpent.Value))`

Comment: Thank you Alwaysariyana.

Comment: Solution:

    =(sum(cint(left(Fields!time_spend.Value,1))) +            sum(cint(left(right(Fields!time_spend.Value,5),2))) \60 ) & ":" &         sum(cint(left(right(Fields!time_spend.Value,5),2))) mod 60 & ":" &         sum(cint(right(Fields!time_spend.Value,2)))